# When to put logic in angularjs services over plain javascript classes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have **angularjs** **controllers** where there is lot of logic. I am looking at re-factoring the controller logic and have come up with two options. Either to move all the controller logic to **services** or to **plan javascript class** by creating public methods.

The **code** that I want to move out of **controller** is not **reusable**.  Please note that the logic consists of transforming the data to different object formats, array manipulations, convert data to different format before binding to UI or before posting to backend etc. I am also using **ViewModel** which is a **plain javscript class** that does some basic data transformations from **model** data (api data) to **bindable ui data**.

So what are the benefits that I am going to get by moving the **logic** to **services** over **plain javascript classes**?. The main motive to move my logic out of controller is to make the code **more testable** (by making the logic as public methods) and to have controllers with only **UI interaction** and **api calls** code.

Comment: I personally learned a lot by reading this : https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: AngularJS **service providers** are injectable. You can inject other services including the built-in ones: `$http`, `$q`, `$timeout`, `$document`, `$window`, etc. This makes them **unit testable**.